# Same Conversion Tracking Code, Multiple Conversions

Tags: analytics, google-ads-api

This question is in regard to Google AdWords conversion tracking. My client already has conversion tracking on the confirmation page that appears when users successfully sign up for a trial account, but they want to use the same conversion tracking code for confirmation pages that display when they convert their trial account to a paid subscription. They want to see how many trial accounts are being converted to paid accounts/subscriptions. Can they use the same conversion tracking code on multiple confirmation pages? Or should they set up a separate conversion tracking code to track conversions from trial to paid accounts? What is the best practice, and the best way to track how many trial accounts are converting to paid accounts?

Thank you in advance for any insight and/or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

They could use the same conversion tracking code in different places, but I would not recommend that because later it will be difficult to differentiate between both conversions.

I AdWords you have multiple types of conversions, my suggest is that they should use different conversions for each conversion action.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I created a separate conversion code for each conversion type.

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to differentiate the conversions.
1. You setup different conversion types in your adwords account and set the tags on the pages relevant pages 
- free trial thank you page
- paid subscription thank you page.

2. Same conversion tag, but you update the values within the script to reflect the "steps" in the conversion funnel.

Option 1 - is much easier to implement.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Much appreciated.